# Measuring network usage by socket connection in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to measure how many bytes a particular socket sends/receives inside java? I'm writing server software for EC2 in java and I'm looking to minimize the bandwidth usage. I would like to be able to record statistics of what calls to the server cause the most bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to wrap your send/receive calls in a [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) and [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html).